# query pg_stat_bgwriter is very slow

Tags: postgresql

i'm running a PostgreSQL 9.5.10. 
since two days the regular Monitoring queries are significantly slower than usual.

e.G. the following query takes alway 10 seconds and similar queries (pg_stat_database, pg_stat_database_conflicts) are also very slow. The regular user based operations are performing fine.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_bgwriter;
```

i also find Messages about stale stats in the postgresql logfile

```
LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

how can i fix this situation without

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to figure out the problem with your statistics collection.

- Check if the statistics collector is running (a process called `stats collector process`).
- Check if the UDP socket for statistics collection is there: `netstat -u -n -p`
- `strace` the statistics collector to see what it is doing.

It is hard to guess the cause of such a problem without investigating, see [this blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/).

Comment: The Blogpost covers exactly my Situation. We had to deactivated IPv6 and didnt restart the database. Which lead to a stale stats collector which just didnt get any UDP Packages.
Restarting the database fixed our problem